# Configuring nginx to work with WordPress Multisite - 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns, multisite

I am having issues with trying to get a WordPress Multisite (using subdomains) running on nginx.

Here is my ideal set-up:

```
domain.com
sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.com
sub3.domain.com
```

Any requests to `www.domain.com` should be 301'd to `domain.com` (my understanding is that WordPress strips out www anyways?)

I am not wanting to access any of the subdomains by any other means, e.g `domain2.com` would direct a user to `sub2.domain.com` - this isn't what I want.

I have followed this [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-single-and-multiple-wordpress-site-settings-with-nginx) and everything has worked fine with regular WordPress installs.

My **local** hosts file is set up as follows:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX domain.com
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX sub1.domain.com
```

etc...

My issue is that whenever I attempt to visit either `domain.com` or `sub*.domain.com`, I am redirected to a completely different site on my server, the one which just so happens to be the top of the list in `sites-enabled`. On closer inspect, when checking the Network tab in Chrome, I can see that my request for `domain.com` or `sub*.domain.com` is 301 redirected to the aforementioned unrelated site.

I have flushed my local Chrome cache, am constantly using Incognito mode and I just cannot shake this redirect. I'm even using Firefox as I rarely use it so wouldn't expect any caching whatsoever for `domain.com`

I may be completely off the mark here and it could be nothing to do with the browser at all but rather the server and nginx configuration. Something is forcing a 301 and I don't know what.

It seems that [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) comes up a lot in discussion but as far as I can tell, this is only applicable when wanting to map a regular domain to a subdomain, which isn't what I want.

Can anyone please offer any advice/solutions as to how I can configure so everything is routed correctly? My local environment runs a LAMP stack so I have had this working and I have altered the `wp-config.php` file to reflect the new 'live' domain (remember, I have not configured DNS, I have just hacked around in `etc/hosts`.

Any help much appreciated as always :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I decided to build the multisite from scratch in my nginx environment as opposed to trying to take what worked in Apache and re-configure for nginx. As far as I can tell, I had updated everything that you would expect to have to do so from Apache to nginx as well as updating local domains to live ones in the database and wp-config.

While this approach didn't strictly 'fix' my issue, I do feel like I've learned a valuable lesson here - sometimes starting from scratch is better than trying to make something fit!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that avoids your request to be served by the "fallback", default vhost (that is, the "first" there) is the `server_name` directive.

Just by specifying `location` blocks in multiple `server` blocks with the same (or no) `server_name` won't make them magically match.

You *can* however use regular expression server names.

[See here for how.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names)

For the specific case with only a single domain, you can use

`server_name *.whatever.com;`

then match `location` with `return 301 http://whatever.com;` for subdomains only. That way you will not need regular expression server names.

Note that you **should** have server_name for the default server, like

`server_name "_";`

Comment: Unfortunately Regex (or indeed server administration) are not a strong point for me. Are you able to offer any further assistance, please? I have managed to remove the 301 and now stuck in a 302.

Comment: Sure but what is your current progress?
BTW WordPress can not manage 301/www on nginx, but via apache .htaccess only.

Comment: Altogether, you must have a server block with `server_name domain.com`, one *another* with `server_name www.domain.com`, and yet one *for each subdomain*, that is, `subX.domain.com`. This usually means separate files (5 for 3 subdomains) in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` **and** the corresponding symbolic links in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

Comment: Thank you, Victor. I will try that ASAP.